# Mercurial - Pull changes after Clone

Tags: mercurial

Say I cloned a remote repository and called it **"A"**
Then I cloned another remote repository and called it **"B"**

**"B"** has the `.hg` folder and `src` folder , and **"A"** only has the `.hg` folder.

If I pull changes from **"B"** to **"A"**, should now **"A"** also contain the `src` folder? Because that's exactly what I did and it did not

Comment: Are A and B cloned from completely unrelated repositories, or forks of the same repository?

Answer (score 0):

You mix the concepts of 'repository' with the working directory, the actually checked-out changeset, which indicates the state of the repository at a particular revision.

If the two repositories *A* and *B* are pulled into one repository, all changesets are present there, but they are present in different changesets. If you want to bring them together, you have to merge two changesets; most likely you want to merge the two heads you have, the one from repository *A* and the one from repository *B*. For example:

```
# check heads:
hg heads --template="{rev}:{node|short} {desc}\n"
2332:d69c8aaf6db6 Doc: Changelog as it should have been
2128:6f38df710194 Added tag 0.2.5 for changeset 6d89bb9ad3f6
```

Update to one head and then merge the other. Make sure to use the actual revisions:

```
hg up -r2332
hg merge -r2128
```

Whether or not that works without any conflicts depends on how *A* and *B* look like.

Answer (score 0):

Does `src` contain any files? You cannot add an empty directory to a mercurial repo. If you tried `hg add src` and `src` was empty, you won't get an error but nothing happens. If that's really what you want, [there are ways](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html#id361216), but it sounds like you're just experimenting.

More specifically: You can only add files, and the directories that contain them are added implicitly.  After you create a file in `src`, `add` the file to the repo and `commit` the change (along with anything else you may want to bring along). Now you have a changeset you can push or pull to repository **"B".**

Once the changeset has become part of **"B"**'s history (check with `hg log`), you need to update to it (`hg update`); or, if you've ended up with a branch, merge it to your current branch.